# How to measure voltage of each bank in a Marx Generator?

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-measurement

If I have a 10 stage Marx generator with each stage at 2.5kV, when I erect all the stages the last stage's negative terminal will be at 22.5kV with respect to ground.

If I want a voltage measurement of these capacitors what is the best way to do this?  I am worried about violating the standoff internal to my differential probes   since the probes would all share a common ground on the supply/measurement side.

Comment: What value Line input and C value for each stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VR37000003005JR500](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28907/vr25vr37vr68.pdf)  30MΩ 3.5kV working voltage

IEC 60950-1-07  PCB Pollution Level 1 creepage 4mm/kV > 1kV

[image: schematic]

Use ~ 1cm air gap around the body to nearest part or above cellulose or dry wood substrate.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a shot

Answer (score 1):

Make e.g. a voltage divider with 30 resistors that rated for 1kV each. When needed, use a capacitor parallel to each resistor to compensate for parasitic capacitance of the resistors.
Benefit of using multiple resistors is that a high resistance can easier (lower cost/availability) be achieved and power dissipation is distributed over more resistors.

Answer (score 1):

For measuring these kinds of high voltages, you might consider using a shielded copper sulphate (\$\text{CuSO}_4\$) solution in a cylinder of perspex as one of the resistors in a resistive voltage divider. You can decide on the divider ratio to use used.

Typically, a hollow perspex cylinder is used with a dilute solution of \$\text{CuSO}_4\$ using de-ionized water. For example, in this case you might use a cylinder that is \$30\:\text{cm}\$ long and \$1\frac14\:\text{cm}\$ in diameter. (Increasing the cross-sectional area improves the non-inductive behavior.) The cylinder design also suppresses the effect of coupling capacitance with the surroundings. Advantages for using a solution of \$\text{CuSO}_4\$ is that it is easy to adjust to the resistance you want for the divider (given some other value you've also chosen for the non-inductive carbon film resistors used in parallel, perhaps, to make up the other resistor of the divider), it can withstand many megavolts across it, and you can make it in a variety of convenient shapes.

Enclose the non-inductive carbon film resistors (use a number of them in parallel for the value you want -- do not use just one by itself) in an aluminum cylinder that extends partway up the outside of the perspex cylinder to provide shielding from EMI for the non-inductive, parallel carbon film resistor group.

Look these up on the web. They are built and used very often for Marx generator voltage measurements in laboratories.